# How to pipe stdout into stdin of optipng?

Tags: cat, stdout, stdin

Is there any way to do something like this: (or why below code doesn't work?)

```
type input.png | optipng -out output.png
```

*p.s: `type` is Windows version of `cat` Unix command*

Answer (score 1):

According to the [manual](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/optipng-0.7.7.man.pdf) `optipng` expects its input files to be specified as a parameter, so it doesn't seem to support reading a file from stdin. The default way of handling PNGs is to optimize the files in-place (which wouldn't work for data read from stdin) so there probably isn't an easy workaround for this.

Comment: The problem is, OptiPNG doesn't work if file name contains non-ASCII chars, so I'm trying to find a solution for it.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani rename the file :-) Or submit a defect report/feature request, see links on http://optipng.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @MehdiDehghani There seem to be others with the same issue, see https://sourceforge.net/p/optipng/feature-requests/54/

Comment: `Created: 2016-07-17`, so seems like they won't change their code, I guess that's because `fopen` method. optipng should work with non-ASCII file names in linux and macos. the only problem in windows.